# Pygame is not working in pycharm just a black window pops up

Tags: python, events, pygame

I'm using this bit of code in pycharm, but none of the print for events works(the quit, mouse button click or key pressing on keyboard)

Although I see the pygame window but the events doesn't work.

I also used the get() instead of wait() but still no luck.

any ideas?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while True:
    event = pygame.event.wait()

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        print('Quit')

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print('Key Down')
        print(event.key)
        print(event.unicode)

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        print('Key Up')
        print(event.key)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print('Mouse Button Down')
        print(event.pos)
        print(event.button == pygame.BUTTON_RIGHT)
        print(event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        print('Mouse Button Up')
        print(event.pos)
        print(event.button == pygame.BUTTON_RIGHT)
        print(event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        print('Mouse Motion')
        print(event.pos)
        print(event.rel)
```

UPDATE
I found out that it's a problem with pycharm.
when I run any code with pygame just a black pygame windows pop up, it doesn't run any other code(events, filling window with color ,...). Even the pygame window is not in dimensions that I've given.

Here another code example.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

red = (255, 0, 0)
screen.fill(red)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.delay(10000)
```

when I run it in VS code:

[Vs code pygame test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxvRL.png)

and when I run it in pycharm :( :

[Pycharm pygame test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxKpQ.png)

also I'm defining the same Interpreter for both VS code and pycharm and I've already reinstalled pygame package.

Comment: What do you see in your PyCharm run console? Your print statements appear to be working there.

Comment: @RSH It's working for me too. I hope you are not expecting to see the prints in pygame window, because the prints will rather appear in IDE's console.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW No i know that it must appear in IDE console.
I found out that it is rather a problem with pycharm cause I tested it in VS code and it worked!!

Comment: @RSH It's strange, I'm using PyCharm, working for me. It would be interesting to find the cause in your case :)

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere nothing prints there!

Comment: If you've found out what the problem was, instead of editing the question, you could post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a full game loop, as this would update the window repeatedly.

Try:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

red = (255, 0, 0)
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(red)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type = pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using pycharm but all the code did not wok so i right clicked it with the mouse and selected run in python cnsole.
OR       ::::::::::::
SHIFT + ALT + E

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you had run a different py file on pycharm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).